# Using RDoc and Executing Code - Annotating

Tags: ruby, annotations, rdoc

I have a series of Ruby methods andI would like to dump their return values out to a formatted report. However, I'd also like to annotate these results (i.e. with descriptions of what the value is), and I was wondering if I could use the existing comments on each method to do this annotating?

So I guess what I want to do is output the rdoc as normal but for each method *actually run the method* with an argument. The argument is the same for every single method, which simplifies it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with 1.9 there is a Method#source_location that might be helpful for you (ripper might help,too).
Also note: http://github.com/rdp/arguments might be helpful